# Retrieve Android Market mylibrary with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to retrieve [this](https://market.android.com/mylibrary) page using curl in php. This page of course requires you to log in because it displays different apps for each user. I have been following the work done on [this page](http://nhenze.net/?p=289), however am not having much success.

So far, in his example I am able to successfully populate the auth variable with the auth token. In the next step however (Below the comment for logging into Android Market) I run into troubles. The output variable that he says should have a 302 code results in a "The document has moved" page which links me back to the Google log in page.

Here is a pastebin to show exactly what I am trying. http://pastebin.com/9Fs9GWxk
Additionally if anyone knows what steps I need to do after this to actually get the page I need that would be amazing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I came up with today for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off) that has been modified to work for you:

```
<?php

$USERNAME = 'you@gmail';
$PASSWORD = 'yourpasswd';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux x86_64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
  'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https://market.android.com/mylibrary');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$formFields = getFormFields($data);

$formFields['Email']  = $USERNAME;
$formFields['Passwd'] = $PASSWORD;
unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

// var_dump($formFields);

$post_string = '';
foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
    $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
//var_dump($result);

if (preg_match('/^2\d{2}/', curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) == false) {
    die("Login failed");
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch), $result);
} else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://market.android.com/mylibrary');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    echo $result;
}

function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        die('didnt find login form');
    }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}
```