# multiple actions with curl

Tags: php, session, curl

I'm trying to do two actions with curl:
 1. Login into admin page
 2. Submit a form (add user)
The first one go fine but the second show error as not loged in.
Here is my code:

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://admin.example.com/admin");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=admin&pass=password"); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 


curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://admin.example.com/admin/adduser");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "newu=demo&pass=password");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$mh = curl_multi_init();
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch2);

    // execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running);

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform both of these requests using the same cURL handle.  The problem in using `curl_multi_exec` in this case is that each curl handle has different options and `$ch2` does not reference any cookies.

Also, `curl_multi_exec` performs the requests in parallel which means you may try to add the user before the login request is completed or even started.

Try this instead, it illustrates logging in using `$ch`, and then using it again to add the user.  If the server supports `keep-alive`, then you can add a `keep-alive` header and the same socket connection is re-used for the second request.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://admin.example.com/admin");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=admin&pass=password"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 

$res = curl_exec($ch);

// check $res here to see if login was successful

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://admin.example.com/admin/adduser");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "newu=demo&pass=password");

$res = curl_exec($ch);

// check $res to see that the user was successfully created

curl_close($ch);
```

Here are some other answers showing how to make multiple serial requests to the same site using cURL after logging in.
[Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off/8992557#8992557)
[Retrieve Android Market mylibrary with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958495/retrieve-android-market-mylibrary-with-curl/8998077#8998077)
[PHP Curl - Cookies problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522149/php-curl-cookies-problem/7532730#7532730)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by using `curl_multi`, you are executing both requests at the same time. The form submitting request will be sent at the same time as the login request, so the login cookies will not be available yet.

Additionally, you're not passing the cookies to the form request at all. You forgot to do this:

```
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

You should do both requests separately to ensure that the proper login cookies are available for the form request.