# CURL to submit form with rotating key

Tags: php, regex, security, curl, http-headers

I'm attempting to create an automated script on my own site which logs into the site, passes some POST Headers and essentially starts an export.

However, I am having difficulty getting passed the login page since there is a rotating key that is different on every page load.

I have tried running the script with no avail, the script below outputs the $xid at the top.  But if I check the $xid echoed it is not the same as the current xid value on the page.

Edit: Good question Norman - It's just your simple hidden field with a random value that changes every time the page is reloaded.  So basically it seems I have to find the xid of a page before 'curl_exec'-ing it which I don't know how to do or if it's even possible.  Maybe this requires some JS along with CURL.

Edit2: [Here is an example URL for the demo](http://demo.x-cart.com/demo/admin/home.php)

Any ideas as to how to get around this?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

# Begin Header info
$url = "https://secure.mywebsite.com/admin/import.php?mode=export";
$post = "mode=export&data%5yaddayaddayadda";
$agent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008100922 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/3.0.3';
# End Header Info

# Begin Processing Info
$ch = curl_init($url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
# End Processing Info


# Begin finding xID
$regex = '/name=\"xid\" value=\".*?\"/';
preg_match_all($regex,$content,$match);
$xid = substr($match[0][0], 18, -1);
echo $xid;
# End finding xID

    # Begin Header info
    $url = "http://secure.mywebsite.com/admin/";
    $post = "username=myusernamehere&password=mypasswordhere&mode=login&usertype=P&xid=".$xid."&redirect=admin";
    $agent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008100922 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/3.0.3';
    # End Header Info

    # Begin Processing Info
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    # End Processing Info


# Begin connection to export file
$url = "https://secure.mywebsite.com/admin/import.php?mode=export";
$post = "mode=export&data%5yaddayaddayadda";
# End connection to export file

# Begin Export
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
# End export

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean rotating key? If there is a token, as I think it is, then you probably want to store the session/cookie that you got along with the first request and then use that with the key along with all other details to submit.

Comment: Well, your curl request is exactly a post request. I'm not sure what exactly the form is doing in this respect. I mean a token for mitigating CSRF makes sense, and that's what the rotating key may be for. It looks like you know what you are doing, but I think you may need to store the cookie from the first request and reuse it/ (exactly what I said in the first comment.) Otherwise if this website is online, please link.

Comment: A couple suggestions: You also need to specify `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` on each request.  The COOKIEJAR is where cookies are written when you call `curl_close`, the COOKIEFILE is where cookies are read from when a request is made.  You can also re-use the same curl handle over and over to reduce code.  All you need to do is change the URL, method, and post data on each request.  I have answered several similar questions.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549892/multiple-actions-with-curl/9549990#9549990) which links to several other answers demonstrating what you want to do.

Comment: In particular, the answer in the above link showing how to log into the Android market shows regex which extracts various CSRF and tokens from hidden fields in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Request

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Second Request:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie.txt');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```